# DropDownList with web part connection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, dropdown

I want to be able to display a dropdown list of titles in a web part and when I select an item have the details populate in another web part.

I can get this to work with a list web part where I have a web part connection that filters on the title, but when I change the list to a dropdown list it stops functioning. I can see all the items in the dropdown list but nothing happens when I pick an item.

It seems like it may have something to do with a postback.

Comment: I need it to show related information also. WhenI pick something in the drop down I want it to show the details of the list item along with the related items.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you use an html form web part you can add whatever code you like in the html source. Connect it to another web part and it will filter it.
Example (drop down is the html form, list below is the target): 
http://wb2-web.sharepoint.com/Pages/o365answers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about a plain vanilla list web part with the preview pane style applied? Hover over the title and the details will show in the preview pane. Out of the box.